# "Wortwörtlich" et similia

Tags: compound, word-formation

Wortwörtlich translates as “word for word”

Tagtäglich as “day by day”

Are there any other examples of this formation? Does it have any rationale (etymological or otherwise)?

Comment: _"Wortwörtlich translates as “word for word"_ It translates as _literally_  or _verbatim_ as well. I don't see actually what you're asking about.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I am asking whether there are other examples for an unusual word-formation: X + X (umlaut) + lich.

Comment: Like _Stündlich_? (Which breaks your claimed rule). I don't think there's a regularly rule to apply.

Comment: @c.p. No, I am not asking about -lich. I am asking about the reduplication of the stem before the suffix -lich. Can you think of any other examples?

Comment: Und wer behauptet, es sei eine Regel? Ich bestimmt nicht.

Comment: I don't see the point of asking what the question is, when it's as clear as it gets. The Op is asking if there are other examples of the construction after this pattern. As simple as that. What is this closing-eagerness about, really??

Comment: @Beta What's the eagerness to leave such moot questions open? How this question is considered useful for future research?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "I don't understand why someone would want to know that" is not one of the valid close reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are, but they are not very common

> stundstündlich
>
> jahrjährlich
>
> nachtnächtlich
>
> malmälich

You even can consider them extremely rare. Rather to be found in poetry (i.e. creative use of language), not ordinary utilitarian texts.

Comment: Thanks. The DWB has one reference only for jahrjährlich, and a couple for nachtnächtlich. So they are rare, but good authors regarded them as acceptable.

Comment: @fdb It fully depends on context. In a newspaper article they would stand out as strange or manieristic. In some piece of artistic literature, they would be considered creative.

Comment: Jetzt spreche ich schon seit mehr als 50 Jahren Deutsch, aber keines der vier aufgezählten Wörter ist mir jemals untergekommen, und in Wiktionary und Duden findet man zumindest stundstündlich auch nicht (die anderen habe ich nicht nachgesehen). Wie kommt es also dazu, dass du so selbstbewusst diese Liste publizierst? Warum stehen ähnliche Wörter (monatmonatlich, minutminütlich, ...) nicht in deiner Liste?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. Wie ich bereits geschrieben habe, hat das DWB von Grimm & Grimm & al. Belegstellen zumindest für jahrjährlich und nachtnächtlich, auch wenn diese Wörter in der Gegenwartssprache nicht geläufig sind.

Comment: Es ist keine Frage der Einstellung, ob man die Wörter als extrem selten betrachtet, sondern sie sind extrem selten - Punkt. Es ist auch nicht so, dass man sich 100 Gedichtbände kaufen kann, und dann früher oder später auf eins davon stößt, im Gegensatz zu einem Wort wie "gülden", für die ich das nicht bestreiten würde.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich kuck mal, ob ich meine Belegstellen in der Belletristik finde... ich meinte, man müsste mal bei Robert Gernhardt kucken? - Was Dinge wie *monatmonatlich* angeht: Ich denke, diese sind nicht in Gebrauch (auch nicht in sporadischem), weil sie zu holprig sind. *Stundstündlich* hat eine rhytmische Eleganz, *monatmonatlich* ist zu umständlich.

Answer (score 3):

The phenomenon is called *Reduplikation* or *Iteration*, and you have chosen the two most prominent and probably the only two accepted as "real word" examples for this in the German language. The words are built this way to sound interesting, are easier to understand (forbabies) or amplify the meaning. Sometimes they also are loanwords, made to sound ridiculous.

If you accept Children's language, and even slight variations to the duplications, here's an absolutely non-exhaustive list of some other more or less exact reduplications (interesting how some of these are present or lead to other reduplicated words in foreign languages)

- Pipi (Urine in kid's language)
- Kaka (Feces in kid's language)
- Papa (Father)
- Mama (Mother)
- Bimbam (Bell in kid's language)
- Töfftöff (Anything with an engine, car)
- Pinkepinke (money)
- Blitzblank (shiny, variation)
- stocksteif (stiff like a stock)
- Schnickschnack (knick-knack - See how the English translation is again a reduplication)
- Singsang (singsong, compare the English)
- sowieso (anyway, with variation)
- Wirrwarr (tangle)
- Mischmasch (hotchpotch (!))
- Hokuspokus (mumbo jumbo)
- Flickflack (back handspring, from French)
- Blabla (that's obvious)
- plemplem (to be gaga)
- ballaballa (again *gaga*)
- Knickerbocker (slight variation, English loan-word)
- Firlefanz (from French *virelay*, folderol)

*grundgütig* and *tieftraurig* are maybe no reduplications but follow a very similar pattern.

Comment: "Hokus pokus" doesn't belong in this group, as it probably is a distortion of " Hoc est enim corpus meum", which is a part of the Credo..

Comment: @Beta so what? It's still a pretty close reduplication. The nature of a reduplication very often *is* a distortion of a foreign word. *Ballaballa* (another clear reduplication) stems from ital. *ballare*

Comment: _@tofro_ None of your listed examples are ***re***duplications as kind of asked for the examples in the question. Nice try though.

Comment: Ok, machen wir den Test: Was bedeutet Pi? Was ist Ka? Was sind Pa und Ma für Wörter? Oder Bim? Mir scheint kein einziges Wort Deiner Liste genügt den in der Frage aufgestellten Kritierien. Du hast sie extrem aufgeweicht und eine ähnliche, aber deutlich andere Frage beantwortet, und versuchst den Mangel an Qualität durch Quantität zu kompensieren. Das gibt ein Miminus von mir.

Comment: @userunknown Du darfst gerne den Begriff *Reduplikation* oder *Iteration* in einem linguistischen Fachbuch nachschlagen und deinen Kommentar nochmal überdenken. Wenn du natürlich einfach *der Meinung bist*, dass die Antwort falsch ist, darfst du auch gerne ein Minus geben.

Comment: Ich brauch Deine Erlaubnis nicht um Dir ein Minus zu geben. Aber angenommen ich glaube Deinen Büchern, dass die Wörter deiner Liste Reduplikationen sind und dass auch wortwörtlich eine ist, dann ist deine Liste immer noch falsch, weil Reduplikation eben eine zu grob gefasste Obermenge dessen ist, was der Frager gefragt hat. Stocksteif ist übrigens eine Alliteration in einem Wort aber auch wenn wortwörtlich eine Alliteration enthält ist das eben eine zu grobe Kategorie um zu erfassen, was gefragt war.

Answer (score 3):

A similar doubling in the word formation as in *wortwörtlich* (word-for-word) or *tagtäglich* (day-to-day) we might also want to consider for the technical term ***eineindeutig*** (one-to-one) as in

> *eine eineindeutige Abbildung* (a representation having a one-to-one correspondence with its original)

Comment: Ist es nicht. "Wortwörtlich" ist nur eine Bekräftigung der Bedeutung "wörtlich". Eine eineindeutige Abbildung ist aber eine strengere Definition einer Abbildung, als eine eindeutige. Eindeutig heißt, dass für jedes a in A genau ein b mit f(a) = b existiert. So ist a² eindeutig für ganze Zahlen A. Es ist aber nicht eineindeutig, denn das würde bedeuten, dass auch für jedes b in f(a) = b nur ein a existiert, aber a²=b hat für 3 und -3 die Lösung 9. Es ist also eine eindeutige, aber keine eineindeutige Relation.

Comment: @userunknown I think Loong gave a good example here. The difference is, that it is not build with "lich"...
wortwörtlich: There is "wörtlich" with the meaning of literally. And the reduplication "wortwörtlich" is literally too, but stronger.
Exactly the same is valid for "eineindeutig" as you explained: eineindeutig is more eindeutig.
All three examples share the property, that the original word "seems to" not being suitable for building a comparative out of it.
Täglich is alredy every day (with some exceptions maybe). Tagtäglich is every f***ing day!

Comment: @IngoBochmann: Eineindeutig ist keineswegs eine Bekräftigung von Eindeutig, sondern inhaltlich etwas anderes. Es ist keine Steigerung (Quantität) von eindeutig sondern eine ganz andere Bedeutung (Qualität). Wortwörtlich ist weder eine Steigerung, noch eine andere Bedeutung, sondern nur eine Unterstreichung.

Comment: @userunknown tagtäglich wortwörtlich und eineindeutig haben gemeinsam, dass sie "eine strengere Definition" (sic! by userunknown) von wörtlich, täglich und eindeutig sind.

Comment: @IngoBochmann: Was ist denn an wortwörtlich strenger als an wörtlich?

Comment: @userunknown: inhaltliche/sinngemäße Übersetzung --> wörtliche Übersetzung --> wortwörtliche Übersetzung, oft auch negativ konnotiert ("zu genau", buchstabengetreu)

Comment: @IngoBochmann Wortwörtlich bedeutet also buchstäblich und wörtlich bedeutet sinngemäß? Wo? Du verrennst Dich jetzt massiv, nur um Recht zu behalten. Frag mal Leute die Dich lieben.

Comment: @userunknown Die Pfeile sollen die Steigerungen anzeigen.

Comment: @Ingo: Was kann man denn buchstabengetreu übersetzen? Übersetz mal "apple" buchstabengetreu, ich bin gespannt. Brainfuck (eine Programmiersprache) kann man glaube ich in eine andere Programmiersprache, die nach dem gleichen Muster aufgebaut ist, buchstabengetreu übersetzen - sowas dürfte aber auch kein Hörer oder Leser im Kopf haben. Man kann wörtlich zitieren, wobei zitieren eigentlich schon impliziert, dass es wortgetreu ist, sonst ist es nur eine sinngemäße Wiedergabe. Wortwörtlich zitieren ist nur eine Betonung, dass es wirklich ein Zitat ist und keine Paraphrasierung. Es ist keine Steigr.

Comment: @userunknown Z.B. Bibelstellen: Kann man sinngemäß/inhaltlich übersetzen (was war gemeint?), wörtlich (was genau wird in der Originalversion gesagt?) und wortwörtlich (word-by-word, aber inhaltlich nicht (mehr) korrekt).
Alle drei Beispiele (tagtäglich, wortwörtlich, eineindeutig) haben IMHO gemeinsam, dass eine normale Steigerung nicht sinnvoll erscheint ("täglicher": Mumpitz, "wörtlicher": klingt doof, "eindeutiger": Quatsch). Obwohl das alles grammatikalisch ginge. Mit der Bildung X+X(Umlaut)+"er" wird die "besondere" Art der Steigerung/Verstärkung deutlich gemacht.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85443/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-ingo-bochmann).

Comment: @IngoBochmann Grammatikalisch heißt sprachwissenschaftlich und umfasst die Semantik, daher geht es grammatikalisch nicht.
Gut. Wortwörtlich kann man als "Wort für Wort" auffassen, und wörtlich wäre nicht sinngemäß, wenn es in der einen Sprache ein Sprichwort gibt, das etwa "Der Krug geht solange zum Brunnen bis er bricht" lautet, dass es mit Krug und Brunnen und gehen in einer anderen Sprache nicht gibt, aber es könnte ein gleichbedeutendes Sprichwort geben, etwa "man sitzt in der Hose bis sie reißt". Letzteres wäre dann das, was eine gute, sinngemäße Übersetzung wäre, ...

Comment: wörtlich übersetzt wäre schlecht, weil es die Leser nicht verstehen würden, wortwörtlich wäre noch schlechter, wenn die Reihenfolge von Subjekt/Prädikat/Objekt usw. in der Zielsprache falsch wäre.
Nur: So, im Zusammenhang mit Übersetzungen verwendet man "wortwörtlich" gar nicht, sondern im Zusammenhang mit Zitaten. "Es hat keine Hetzjagden gegeben, das hat er so wortwörtlich gesagt". So wird es verwendet, als Bekräftigung der Richtigkeit eines Zitats.